Short story: Post[-post]-apocalyptic, about a girl who lives in a mansion with a caregiver (NOT WondLa or Keeper of the Isis Light)
(edited post to integrate answers to questions that were asked in a comment)
I remember very little about this story. I probably read it in the early to mid 2000s, but I don't know how old it is. It had a sort of timeless vibe, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was as old as the 80s or maybe even the 60s.
It had at least one illustration, in colour, which I'll describe later in the post. (But I might have read this story in a school textbook, and sometimes textbooks add illustrations to stories that didn't originally have any; so it could be that the original story had no illustrations.)
The girl is fairly young, a preteen or young teen. I think she's an orphan, but there's someone to take care of her. I don't remember if her caregiver is a normal human or some kind of robot or what. I believe the girl's been an orphan for most of her life, so she doesn't really remember or miss her parents, or know any life but this (though I think she knows that the world used to be different).
There don't seem to be any other people around. I think it's stated or implied that there was some kind of disaster, and the girl and her caregiver are just living out their lives in the aftermath in their mansion, and no one else is around that they know of. I don't remember getting the impression that the world itself is a Standard Post-Apocalyptic Setting, though. The one illustration I can remember is colourful and "bright" (though to be fair it's of an indoor scene), and the mansion is large and opulent and intact. The setting might qualify for what TV Tropes calls Cosy Catastrophe.
I think it's just the two of them living there, no other people, no pets or anything. I don't have any recollection of them ever going outside except within the property, e.g. in a yard or something. I think they're supposed to stay there because it's dangerous to leave. But I don't remember why. It's possible that the caregiver is overprotective and it'd actually be fine to leave. Maybe there's just nothing to find and thus no point in leaving.
I think the mansion is in a sort of suburban area. So, in a city, but not necessarily super close to the heart of it. If it's not in the city, then I'm misremembering.
I was asked if this takes place in the US or the UK or some other identifiable place. I sort of assume it takes place in the US, but I'm really not sure. I suppose it could be the UK. It does at least seem to be Earth, I don't remember getting the impression that it wasn't Earth.
The food they eat is described as being some kind of nutrient cubes, or something along those lines. I think they have little or no normal food.
The only illustration I remember is for a scene where the girl stands in a small room in her house that has full wall mirrors on opposite walls, so that she is infinitely reflected. The girl does this on a regular basis to entertain herself; she likes this room. In the illustration, she's wearing a pink dress, and has dark hair past her shoulders. I think maybe she has a bow in her hair, and/or on the front of her dress. (Edit to add: This is the only actual "scene", as opposed to vague impression about the setting and premise, that I have any memory of. Even if I have almost every other detail wrong, I'm pretty confident this scene happens.)
I think there's an undercurrent of the girl being lonely and bored. I was asked how else she entertains herself (e.g. books, music, dolls). I don't remember anything about that except for visiting the mirror room; but if I had to guess, I would assume she reads books, because I can't imagine what else she would do with her time, and I'd expect a mansion to at least have plenty of books.
In my memory it feels like not much happens for most of the story, and it's mainly setup for something that happens at the end; but I forget what happens at the end. My mind keeps imagining a helicopter, or some other large flying thing, maybe crashing into their lawn or something. Or I could be totally making that up. I don't know.
I don't remember where I read this, except that I know I read it in a physical book, not online. I don't have any ideas about who the author might be. I don't remember any character names or distinguishing features (except that the girl had dark hair in the illustration).
I've tried a lot of different combinations of relevant search terms on Google, and found nothing. In my experience browsing ISFDB tags doesn't help, since I wouldn't recognize the title if I saw it; the only way I could rule a story out is by reading it. I've tried all the relevant TV Tropes pages I can think of, e.g. Food Pills, Future Food Is Artificial, the aforementioned Cosy Catastrophe, etc. I've also posted about it on Reddit several times (on r/tipofmytongue and r/whatsthatbook), but no luck so far. This is my first time asking here.

I've edited the post to respond to your questions.

My first thought on  seeing the title was, "The Keeper of the Isis Light", but it is a novel and not a short story.  And I believe that the girl can and does go outside.

This sounds like The Search for WondLa (2010). Here's the Wikipedia page with the colourful cover image.


Eva Nine had never seen the actual sun before, or walked outdoors. In fact, she had never even seen another living person in all twelve years of her life. That changes when a marauding huntsman destroys her underground home and sends her fleeing for her life. She is desperate to find someone else who is like her, and a single clue gives her hope: a crumbling picture of a girl, a robot, an adult, and the word "WondLa".


Could you please [edit] in the relevant parts of the Wikipedia article in your answer? Rather have the information here and use a link as reference than force people to follow the link to get the info themselves

That isn't a short story, and it's also too new.
